# Error with import statement for FloatingActionButton and Snackbar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on an assignment for an online course on Udacity. The starter code can be found [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code).

The only thing I've done to the starter code was to add a new Activity with `New > Activity > Basic Activity`. I then got import errors in the two lines

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
```

Specifically, I get a `Cannot resolve symbol 'FloatingActionButton'` and same for Snackbar.

I've spent the past hour here (was having another problem before this one, also with import statements but in the MainActivity), and have tried the following:

1. Changing the appcompat on build.gradle file
2. File > Invalidate caches / restart
3. Build > Rebuild project
4. Sync project with Gradle files
5. Re-installing Android Studio

None of this worked.

The build.gradle file is

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

I'm not really sure what started the error(s) to begin with since it's been a complete rabbit whole but I *think* it was after doing some update to Android Studio.

Can anyone please point me to the solution?

Comment: try `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'` and sync your project, make sure you have the inter net

Comment: That worked! Thank you, I spent so much time on this was driving me crazy. Really strange I thought Android Studio would prompt for updates for things like that but there was nothing there.

Comment: it happens some time, though you can look into gradle console or build error details, i also recommend to work with latest dependencies and android studio which improved. i am glad that i could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding dependencies, just use the same dependency version (which is available on local machine) across similar dependency packages so use

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Note : I also recommend to work with latest dependencies and android studio which improved and thus more helpful (there's been some great improvement in latest android studio IDE to handle build errors)